# Implementation of std::is_class

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering how the `std::is_class` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_class/) is actually implemented. I looked at **/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/type_traits** but it seems that the only thing which is there is:

```
/// is_class
template<typename _Tp>
  struct is_class
  : public integral_constant<bool, __is_class(_Tp)>
  { };
```

and the definition of `__is_class` is not to be found anywhere (or I just did not look deep enough). anyway I would be happy if someone could point out to me where to look for this (and also the other `is_***` from the `std` namespace)

Comment: Some of the `type_traits` depend on compiler hooks or intrinsics of some sort - maybe check the GCC source.

Answer (score 3):

`__is_class` is a C++ extension provided by gcc compiler. See [gcc type traits](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Traits.html).

> The C++ front end implements syntactic extensions that allow compile-time determination of various characteristics of a type (or of a pair of types).